# How to add positional information in Lucene's IR model?

Tags: java, lucene, similarity, information-retrieval

I want to implement my own positional-based IR model by extending Similarity class in Lucene. I want to influence document weight according to the matched terms' position in a document. I have searched Google and found no answer. How should I do it?

I am using Lucene 7.2.1

Answer (score 3):

As i am understanding this you want your own Similarity Model for this in lucene core search there is a class called SimilarityBase. Path for this file would be

> lucene-7.2.1\core\src\java\org\apache\lucene\search\similarities

```
public abstract class SimilarityBase extends Similarity
```

A subclass of Similarity that provides a simplified API for its descendants. Subclasses are only required to implement the Score and toString() methods.Implementing `explain(List, BasicStats, int, float, float)`is optional, inasmuch as SimilarityBase already provides a basic explanation of the score and the term frequency. However, implementers of a subclass are encouraged to include as much detail about the scoring method as possible.

Note: multi-word queries such as phrase queries are scored in a different way
  than Lucene's default ranking algorithm: whereas it "fakes" an IDF value for
  the phrase as a whole (since it does not know it), this class instead scores
  phrases as a summation of the individual term scores.
Example code for Overriding Score and Explain Methd

```
@Override
  protected float score(BasicStats stats, float freq, float docLen) {
    return stats.getBoost() *
        distribution.score(
            stats,
            normalization.tfn(stats, freq, docLen),
            lambda.lambda(stats));
  }



 @Override
  protected void explain(
      List<Explanation> subs, BasicStats stats, int doc, float freq, float docLen) {
    if (stats.getBoost() != 1.0f) {
      subs.add(Explanation.match(stats.getBoost(), "boost"));
    }
    Explanation normExpl = normalization.explain(stats, freq, docLen);
    Explanation lambdaExpl = lambda.explain(stats);
    subs.add(normExpl);
    subs.add(lambdaExpl);
    subs.add(distribution.explain(stats, normExpl.getValue(), lambdaExpl.getValue()));
  }
```

To construct an Similarity Model, you must specify the implementations for  all three components of the Information-Based model.

1. **Probabilistic distribution** used to model term occurrence
2. parameter of the probability distribution which average counts number of 
   occurrences of word in the collection or in Avg no of Documents  λ<sub>w</sub> parameter of the probability distribution
3. Term frequency normalization

You can find more details about Normalization here

```
org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Normalization.NoNormalization
```

@ note
 "normal" Lucene queries create scorers, returning null if terms don't exist This means they never score a term that does not exist however with spans, there is only one scorer for the whole hierarchy